# Ubuntu installation problem - Kernel panic

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, kernel

I'm trying to install Ubuntu from USB. The purple screen of Ubuntu doesn't show up, it only says

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x0000000b
```

and stops there.

I tried the USB with another computer and it works perfectly. I thought maybe the problem is my computer which is *Toshiba Satellite L50* but I couldn't find any helpful comment on the internet.

I tried both FAT32 and NTFS as USB format but nothing changes.

I also thought maybe the problem is me using Windows 10 currently and searched for that. I have disabled "Turn on fast startup" but again nothing changes.

I also add [an image of final screen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqB4d.jpg). Please notice that it is the first time I'm trying to install/use Ubuntu.

Thanks for recommendations already.

Comment: Do you have a password set in your BIOS? Have you checked that you have the latest BIOS firmware installed?

Comment: Sorry for late answering.
I don't have password protection in my BIOS.
When I check my BIOS firmware version, via command prompt, it says "SMBIOSBIOSVersion 1.40" and honestly I couldn't figure out what this means. In system information, it says "BIOS version/date : TOSHIBA 1.40, 11.10.2013".

Comment: It looks like you've got an old BIOS 1.40, and if I've gotten to the correct Toshiba support page, there are a number of BIOS updates that have been released since 1.40. See http://support.toshiba.com/support/modelHome?freeText=1200010420&osId=26 but double-check the model number from the tag on the bottom of your computer with that web page to make sure I've got it correct. Lastly, if you have a DVD drive, try burning the Ubuntu .iso to DVD and installing from DVD... I've found it's a lot more reliable than installing from a USB flash.

Comment: thanks for your all comments, I was able to install ubuntu 17.04. I still don't know what the problem was but I'm typing from Ubuntu right now :)

Comment: Did you update your BIOS? Did you install from DVD or USB?

Comment: I didn't update my BIOS, and installed 17.04 from USB. The only thing I've changed was the version of Ubuntu.

Comment: As I mentioned before, you really need to check if my research on your behalf was correct... that you're way behind in BIOS updates. If so, please consider updating it asap. Cheers, Al